# The values of $x$ obtained from the equation $ax^2+by^2=1$ and $ax+by=1$ will be equal if:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, quadratics

> The values of $x$ obtained from the equation $ax^2+by^2=1$ and $ax+by=1$ will be equal if:
>   $$a). a-b=1$$
>   $$b). a+b=1$$
>   $$c). a=b$$
>   $$d). a=b=1$$

My Attempt:
$$ax^2+by^2=1$$
$$x=\sqrt {\dfrac {1-by^2}{a}}$$
and 
$$ax+by=1$$
$$x=\dfrac {1-by}{a}$$
According to the Question,
$$\sqrt {\dfrac {1-by^2}{a}}=\dfrac {1-by}{a}$$
On solving further, I got
$$2a^2b=a^2b(y+by)$$

Comment: Be careful when divide by $a$. In this case if $a=0$, x is indeterminate, so assume $a \neq 0$.

Comment: Also $\frac {1-by} a $ need to be $\geq 0$.

Comment: @user202729 not necessarily, the negative square root could have been taken too.

Comment: Oh yes, so the step $x = \sqrt {1-by^2 \over a}$ should be $x = \pm \sqrt {1-by^2 \over a}$ . BTW because the first equation is quadratic, it is (probably, I think?) impossible for its solution set to coincide at all points with the linear one, unless it is degenerate. So `a=b=0`?

Comment: Yes, I am not sure what the question means. What does "the values of $x$ obtained from these equations" actually mean? You can take any value of $x$ for the linear equation, and any value $-\frac1{\sqrt a}\le x\le\frac1{\sqrt a}$ for the first. Perhaps it could mean that there exist points of intersection between the ellipse and the line, but this is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$ax+by=1 \implies y =\frac{1-ax}{b}$$

Now, substituting this, we get, $$ax^2+b(\frac{1-ax}{b})^2=1 \implies abx^2+a^2x^2-2ax+1-b=0$$

Implying that the value of $x$ obtained is same from the two equations $\equiv$ the quadratic equation has only one root, we then have $$\text{ Discriminant}=0 \implies 4a^2-4(ab+a^2)(1-b)=0$$ $$\implies a^2-ab-a^2+ab^2+a^2b=0$$ $$\boxed{a+b=1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Viewing this problem geometrically and assuming that at least one of $a$ and $b$ is non-zero, the first equation describes a (possibly degenerate) conic section, while the second is a line. For their intersections to have the same $x$-values, the line must either be vertical or tangent to the conic.

In the vertical case, we have $b=0$, so $ax^2=1$ and $ax=1$, which means that $x=a=1$. The conic in this case is degenerate, consisting of the parallel lines $x=\pm1$.

For the second case, we can work in homogeneous coordinates and write the tangency condition in terms of the dual conic’s matrix (using the adjugate to allow zeros for $a$ or $b$) and the homogeneous vector that represents the line: $$\begin{bmatrix}a&b&-1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}-b&0&0\\0&-a&0\\0&0&ab\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\-1\end{bmatrix} = ab-a^2b-ab^2 = -ab(a+b-1) = 0,$$ from which we have $a=0$, $b=0$ or $a+b=1$. The condition $a=0$ allows for any pair of $x$-values, so must be rejected, and we’ve already dealt with $b=0$, leaving $a+b=1$ (which subsumes the $b=0$ case, anyway). The conic is an ellipse for $0\lt a\lt1$, a pair of parallel lines when $a=0$ or $a=1$, and a hyperbola otherwise.